# Calling a function only once after fast calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a search button the user can click.

This search button calls a function. I want to avoid that the function is executed multiple times when the user clicks the search button twice or more (because he thinks that nothing has happened).

I am thinking of using `setTimeout(function(){})` somehow and in the end only call the search function again if the click on the button is at least 3 seconds away from the last click.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n1rcre75/ - I want to be able to click the button twice in a row (after 1 second) but have the execute function only run once

Any ideas?

Comment: Disable the button on first call, then enable it after your process finished.

Comment: Remove the onclick code of button and replace it with "" using javascript, after a specific timeout again put it back. Now, even it button is clicked multiple times the onclick will be executed only once

Comment: Example: Here I want to press the search button twice (after 1 second) and have the div fill with "searching..." only once https://jsfiddle.net/n1rcre75/

Answer (score 3):

Just guard the search:

```
var button = document.getElementById('search');
var runSearch = true;

button.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        if(!runSearch){
                return;
        }

        console.log('do search');

        runSearch = false;          
        setTimeout(function(){
                runSearch = true;
        }, 3000);
});
```

Or, if you don't want to introduce another variable to the scope:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', (function() {
        var runSearch = true;

        return function(evt)  {
                evt.preventDefault();

                if(!runSearch){
                        return;
                }

                runSearch = false;
                console.log('do search');

                setTimeout(function(){
                        runSearch = true;
                }, 3000);
        }
})());
```

Answer (score 1):

took your fiddle and made a few changes, the

```
setTimeout(function(){
//stuff
},3000);
```

is only to simulate the actual searching

https://jsfiddle.net/n4fhaqad/

Answer (score 1):

I created a constructor to handle this in a reusable way. You can provide a delay when you create the object or when you invoke it. It has a default of 300ms.

```
function FunctionInvoker(waitTime) {
    this.timerIdentifier = null;
    this.waitTime = waitTime || 300;

    var self = this;

    this.invoke = function (callback, waitTime) {

        self.cancel();

        self.timerIdentifier = setTimeout(function () {
            self.cancel();
            callback();
        }, waitTime || self.waitTime);
    };

    this.cancel = function () {
        if (self.timerIdentifier != null) {
            clearTimeout(self.timerIdentifier);
            self.timerIdentifier = null;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var functionInvoker = new FunctionInvoker();

functionInvoker.invoke(function () {
     // whatever you want to do (callback function)
     saveMyData(); // for ex: save data
});
```

I used this code when dealing with a slider. The slider was making an AJAX call too many times. By using the functionInvoker I was able to only make the AJAX call when slider keeps the same value for Xms.

Comment: I like this answer the best, smart solution and usage well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button inactive until your search function return success or error, or until the user change the search string.

Comment: My example is a simplified version of the context I need this for - Hence disabling the search is not an option.

Comment: Then just detach the event handler from the onclick event until the search finish or the search string is changed. Also add some kind of loading bar, circle, etc. to show that actually some work is done (this will improve the UX).

Answer (score 0):

When you call you our function from the press event, disable the original button for the time the function runs, for example using the get element by Id:

```
function(foo){
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").disabled = true;

//do your function

document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = false;  
}
```

of course this use case is not perfect for all situations, where for example you want to do additional calls inside the function or even xhr. If you have callbacks you should re-enable the button in those.

Comment: My example is a simplified version of the context I need this for - Hence disabling the search is not an option.

Comment: In my example (https://jsfiddle.net/n1rcre75/) I want to be able to press the search button twice or more (after 1 second) and then only run the function once ...having the option to give a time (after how many seconds the button can be repressed is prefered)

Comment: Context: I am using slickgrid (quite old by now) and the column headers are drawn before the actual content is placed in the grid. I am using a loader animation to "bypass" that time. However slickgrid does not provide an "ondrawgridtodiv" event

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('button').click(function() {
                    $('button').prop('disabled', true);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
                    }, 3000);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that works, but using a variable to set the "search state" is not my prefered option because I will have to set it back to allow a search. I don't want to add another "dependency" but rather work with some delay/timeout function that helps me achieve my goal

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery even if OP never mentioned jQuery, why not use `one`

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution:

```
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Click</button>

<script>
  var running = false;
  function buttonClick(){
        if(running == false){
          running = true;
          //your code
          setTimeout(function(){running = false}, 3000);
        }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic code. You can add **avoid_double_click** class to that link/button on which you want to avoid multiple clicks

```
jQuery('.avoid_double_click').on('click', function(e) {
    var onclick_event = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
    jQuery(this).removeAttr("onclick");
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      jQuery(that).attr('onclick', onclick_event);
    },2000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can be used to make it work without any additional states or parameters that have to be cared for

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpg584pp/